# Authorization error occur on cliking on Sign with google in ado.net

Tags: .net, database, model-view-controller, ado.net, google-oauth

I have this query in account controller regarding google o auth

```
  HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(new 

AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "Account/GoogleLoginCallback" },

 "Google");
```

but getting an authorization error when I run this project and click on the sign in with google

Comment: What does your authorization error look like?

Comment: You probably need to add the redirect URL in your [Google ClientID Authorized redirects URIs](https://imgur.com/a/Dmlw8wv)